# Is the X-csrf-token only available for authenticated users?

Tags: 8, csrf

I am working on a rest api end point. I am noticing that some end points work without X-csrf-token header. Digging into the core revealed the following

```
  // This check only applies if
    // 1. the user was successfully authenticated and
    // 2. the request comes with a session cookie.
    if ($account->isAuthenticated()
      && $this->sessionConfiguration->hasSession($request)
    ) {
      if (!$request->headers->has('X-CSRF-Token')) {
        return AccessResult::forbidden()->setReason('X-CSRF-Token request header is missing')->setCacheMaxAge(0);
      }
```

This means that the X-csrf-token header is only checked for authenticated users. Are anonymous users not required to have this header? This really seems counter-intuitive to  me as I feel that authenticated users already have a session cookie and its the anonymous users that need some kind of validation.

How do we add token validation for anonmyous users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal still doesn't use CSRF tokens for anonymous users. The CSRF token is also checked only when a session is available for the currently logged-in user, and only when the request method declared from the route is not one of the following: *GET*, *HEAD*, *OPTIONS*, *TRACE*.

There are some issues opened for Drupal core, which (at the moment I write this answer) still have to be fixed for Drupal 9.1.x, such as [Allow form tokens to be used on anonymous forms in some cases](https://www.drupal.org/node/1803712) (on January 24, 2024, its status is *Needs work*), [CSRF check always fails for users without a session](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2730351) (*Needs work*), and [X-CSRF-Token request header is missing when using Bearer authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3055260) (*Needs work*).

The only way to add CSRF tokens for anonymous users is creating a new service that duplicates almost all the code in [`CsrfRequestHeaderAccessCheck`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Access%21CsrfRequestHeaderAccessCheck.php/class/CsrfRequestHeaderAccessCheck/8.9.x), possibly using a route requirement that is different from *_csrf_request_header_token* used from Drupal core, and add that route requirement to the routes of your module that needs to be accessible also from anonymous users. Such service should also create a session, if it has not been already created.

Keep in mind that CSRF tokens are requested for those routes that alter data (for example, a route that deletes data from the database). If the route is simply showing data, the CSRF token is not required.